# Global UITableViewCell identifiers, created once in storyboard and used in all tables of the app

Tags: xcode, uitableview, ios5, storyboard

I have an application that loads a cell in various table views. I want this specific cell to be the same across all tables view and every time i change something in its design to be populated in all views.

So far I have the cell creation method inside an object, which is call by all table views. If i make changes to that methods all table view are updated.

I have designed the cell in Storyboard and assign it a unique identifier. I want to keep it that way (not design it programmatically). So far I have to copy/paste the cell to all the tables that it is being used. Is there a solution to create a cell in storyboard that can be used in all table views without having to copy/paste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately we can't create a specifically table view cell in story board.

If you want to maintain a single cell instance for all the tables in the application, you need to to create a singleton instance and need to implement all the delegate and data source methods in that class. While setting the delgate and datesource objects to the table view object, you need to give the singleton instance. So that the implementation of the table view cells is single time through out the application and you don't need to copy paste all these methods for each table.

Answer (score 0):

You can lay out the cell in its own xib file instead, create a `UINib` object from the nib, and associate that with the reuse identifier for your particular table.

Your nib must have a UITableViewCell (or subclass) as its top level object.

In viewDidLoad, you'd have something like:

```
UINib *sharedCell = [UINib nibWithName:@"SharedCell" bundle:nil];
[self.tableView registerNib:cellNib forReuseIdentifier:@"SharedCell"];
```

This way you can use the same design in several storyboards.